# Memory leak on loop iterating over query result set

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm

I need your help with exceeded memory limit in PHP.
This is fragment of my code, which causes the problem:

```
$stmt = $query->execute(); // $stmt is instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement
$before = $stmt->fetch();
while ($after = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // there will be some logic for comparsion of row pairs $before and $after,
    // but once the memory issue is fixed
    $before = $after;
    // tried unset($after); with no effect
}
```

Error message is:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
(tried to allocate 24 bytes) in script.php on line 84
```

Error points on line:

```
while ($after = $stmt->fetch()) {
```

To clarify up, this is my part of my real, running code. This is not pseudocode created just to ask my question. I commented out all logic from the loop to ensure it's not the reason.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually a 'leak', and not just the code really consuming that much memory by either logic, or huge resultsets (either number or rows, or big blobs of data)?

Comment: The point is, that I commented out logic to exclude it from execution. In my post, there is real code without modifications and simplifications.

Comment: OK, then, see point 2 of my comment: how big _is_ your resultset, row wise & blob wise? BTW: if this is MySQL, you could play around with `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY`.

Comment: You can either return a row or 1 bilion (which might be the problem), and maybe the logic that is generating so many results is a bit tough to execute, but we cannot help since you didn't show your query nor give us any information about the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. PDO buffered whole result to memory:
I had to set PDO attribute

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

probably you need to unset `$before`:

```
$stmt = $query->execute(); // $stmt is instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement
$before = $stmt->fetch();
while ($after = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // there will be some logic for comparsion of row pairs $before and $after,
    // but once the memory issue is fixed
    unset($before);
    $before = $after;

}
```

the "leak" may occur when `$before` gets re-assigned in the loop and the old data is not deleted by some garbage collection and/or dangling around in memory still.

Comment: I'm wondering why or how this should happen. Reassigning makes clear that $before is not referencing the relevant object anymore. If no other references are held GC should release it?